# Ubuntu 21.04 cannot resume from suspend

Tags: nvidia, bluetooth, suspend, 21.04, resume

After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.10 computer stops responding on resume from suspend.
The following is printed on the screen during resume attempt:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Display engine push buffer channel allocation failed: 0x65 (Call timed out [NV_ERR_TIMEOUT])
nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0:Failed to allocate display engine core DNA push buffer
nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Display engine push buffer channel allocation failed: 0x65 (Call timed out [NV_ERR_TIMEOUT])
nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0:Failed to allocate display engine core DNA push buffer
```

The only option I found so far to recover from it is to forcibly restart the computer.

I am using `nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary, tested)`

Comment: I already tried changing the driver version. It didn't fix the issue.

Comment: There's a [new kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1925843) that might be at fault. Try booting with an older kernel to see if you still have the problem.